# Is there a way to delete a customer from Quickbooks offline using qbsdk and qbxml?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I want to delete a particular customer from quickbooks using the ListId of that customer . What would be my qbxml request in that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ListDelRq` to delete list-type things (Customers, Items, Vendors, etc.) from QuickBooks.

Refer to the OSR for full syntax:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

Your request will look something like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="9.0"?>
  <QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <ListDelRq>
        <!-- ListDelType may have one of the following values: Account, BillingRate, Class, Currency, Customer, CustomerMsg, CustomerType, DateDrivenTerms, Employee, InventorySite, ItemDiscount, ItemFixedAsset, ItemGroup, ItemInventory, ItemInventoryAssembly, ItemNonInventory, ItemOtherCharge, ItemPayment, ItemSalesTax, ItemSalesTaxGroup, ItemService, ItemSubtotal, JobType, OtherName, PaymentMethod, PayrollItemNonWage, PayrollItemWage, PriceLevel, SalesRep, SalesTaxCode, ShipMethod, StandardTerms, ToDo, UnitOfMeasureSet, Vehicle, Vendor, VendorType, WorkersCompCode -->
      <ListDelType>ENUMTYPE</ListDelType>
      <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
    </ListDelRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .